# How to redesign a table when there isn't some data

Tags: javascript, css, html-table

I have a table that shows some data from database. I want if there isn't data in some `<td>` , the column from next row, to be displayed in its place. This is what I mean:
If I have this kind of table:

When there is no data for example for `$data['created_at']`, it should be displayed `$data['due_date']` in its place.
How could I do that?

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
    <?php if(!empty($data['created_at'])){ ?>
       <strong><?php echo "Created Date:";?>:</strong> <?php echo $data['created_at']; ?>
    <?php } ?>
   </td>
    
    <td colspan="3">
    <?php if(!empty($data['username'])){ ?>
       <strong><?php echo "Username:";?>:</strong> <?php echo $data['username']; ?>
    <?php } ?>
   </td>
  </tr>
  
    <tr>
    <td colspan="3">
    <?php if(!empty($data['due_date'])){ ?>
       <strong><?php echo "Date delivery:";?>:</strong> <?php echo $data['due_date']; ?>
    <?php } ?>
   </td>
    
    <td colspan="3">
    <?php if(!empty($data['copmany'])){ ?>
       <strong><?php echo "Company:";?>:</strong> <?php echo $data['copmany']; ?>
    <?php } ?>
   </td>
  </tr>
  
  </table>
```

Comment: I would think this is where javascript would be used

Comment: What kind of javascript should I use - I would like  to try to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to just omit a row if the result is empty? Simply change the place of your if statement to encompass the td

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <?php if(!empty($data['created_at'])){ ?>
    <td colspan="3">
       <strong><?php echo "Created Date:";?>:</strong> <?php echo $data['created_at']; ?>    
   </td>
    <?php } ?>
    
    
    <?php if(!empty($data['username'])){ ?>
    <td colspan="3">
       <strong><?php echo "Username:";?>:</strong> <?php echo $data['username']; ?>
         </td>
    <?php } ?>

  </tr>
  
    <tr>
 
    <?php if(!empty($data['due_date'])){ ?>
         <td colspan="3">
       <strong><?php echo "Date delivery:";?>:</strong> <?php echo $data['due_date']; ?>
     </td>
           <?php } ?>

    
    
    <?php if(!empty($data['copmany'])){ ?>
      <td colspan="3">
       <strong><?php echo "Company:";?>:</strong> <?php echo $data['copmany']; ?>
    </td>
        <?php } ?>
   
  </tr>
  
  </table>
```

Comment: I tried in this way, but if there isn't data for `$data['created_at']` - it's blank and data from next row - `$data['due_date']` should go in the place of `$data['created_at']` but it doesn't.

Comment: Then you will need to do a count of the number of columns that have an empty value and loop through adding <td></td> at the end until the correct column count is reached.

Comment: I didn't understand. I don't need to add <td></td> but value from td from next row that is under `td` which doesn't have data. Srry for bad explanation.

Comment: if you add the <td></td> for each of the empty results you get before the </tr> your data will fill in left to right as you mentioned you had wanted.

Comment: I tried that from @Slawa Eremkin answer but it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: I think i am understanding you now.. to clarify.. if one of the <td>'s is empty omit the entire row?  I will submit another answer for that.

Comment: No, if one <td> value is missing, the value from the td which stands below it, should goes in its place. I mean in my example $data['due_date'] has to go in previous td - in the place of $data['created_at'] - when $data['created_at'] has no data.

Comment: So you want to compress the data as it is displayed even though it would be breaking the structure in the database moving a row value then adjusting all subsequent rows values as well?

Comment: Yes, now I think if I change my table structure to have only one tr and 2 tds - two columns. In first column in sepatare rows to be these data which now is in new line. And in this way, if I have only 2 columns - if some data is missing, there won't be blank space. Is it a good idea?